# The difference between wrapping a require_once inside a conditional statement and not doing so in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, require-once

Without the conditional statement:

```
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . "/edit_info_check_password.php" );
```

works fine. 
But by simple adding:

```
if(  substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 18, 13) == "edit-userinfo" )
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . "/edit_info_check_password.php" );
```

inside the functions.php file, then the functions inside the required file do not work completely.  But they work partially.  Why can't I keep the condition if i only want to include the file for a certain page?

EDIT - additional requested info:
basically trying to add the following actions inside the required file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_ajax_setup' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax-checkpasswords', 'check_info_passwords' );
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax-checkpasswords", "check_info_passwords");
```

The admin ajax setup function runs perfectly, it enqueues two javascript files and localized the admin ajax for javasscript access.  That's great, but my jquery ajax function returns response 0.  Whereas without the conditional statement, I get the full response. Obviously adding the condition changes the way functions.php works with required files.

Comment: I don't believe there is enough info in your question for us to answer this. Please add some details on how the functions "do not work completely".

Comment: When the condition is present, the file may or may not conditionally be included. What effect this has on the rest of the script we cannot tell, since we a) don't know what that file does and b) what exactly the "non-working" part entails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because your ajax admin hooks are not being called.

The reason the ajax hooks are not called is because they are not called at the "edit-userinfo" page. Those ajax calls are handled at a different page. Your require will only load on the "edit-userinfo" page.

The best solution I have is to wrap the ajax hooks in the init hook and the add an `is_admin` conditional check.

This means that you will need to include your file without the conditional. I don't think performance should be an issue if that file is included every time.

You setup your file like this:

```
if(  substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 18, 13) == "edit-userinfo" )
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_ajax_setup' );

function init_admin_ajax_hooks()
{
    if (is_admin()) {
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax-checkpasswords', 'check_info_passwords' );
        add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax-checkpasswords", "check_info_passwords");
    }
}
add_action('init', 'init_admin_ajax_hooks');
```

I left your enqueue script hook as is because I'm not sure if it's in the admin or not.

If it is in the admin you should use `admin_enqueue_script` hook instead:

```
if(  substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 18, 13) == "edit-userinfo" )
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_ajax_setup' );
```

Comment: You are right, the ajax actions were not being loaded, which means that anytime you are localizing the admin ajax file inside a programmer defined function, that function must be included before PHP creates the $_SERVER header.  I was thinking the $_SERVER header would be first but I guess not.